# Anomaly with response coming from XML RPC Api get Post (integer out of range)

Tags: images, xml-rpc

I am getting the following xml snippet back from a getPost call...

```
<member>
    <name>image_meta</name>
    <value>
        <struct>
            <member>
                <name>aperture</name>
                <value>
                    <double>4</double>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>credit</name>
                <value>
                    <string>XXX, YYY</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>camera</name>
                <value>
                    <string>Canon EOS-1D</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>caption</name>
                <value>
                    <string>21/01/2015 AB Preliminary
                        Banking House DC where it continues its XY Street,
                    </string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>created_timestamp</name>
                <value>
                    <int>-62169984000</int>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>copyright</name>
                <value>
                    <string>Copyright ABHCD Photo Agency</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>focal_length</name>
                <value>
                    <string>16</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>iso</name>
                <value>
                    <string>500</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>shutter_speed</name>
                <value>
                    <string>0.004</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>
                    <string>PHOTO ORIENTATION</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>orientation</name>
                <value>
                    <int>1</int>
                </value>
            </member>
        </struct>
    </value>
</member>
```

The problem is in the created_timestamp...

It is out of range of an integer (in java at least and I'd assume on almost all platforms) but the xml specifies its type as integer.

I assume this is a bug? although the fact that it's minus on a date range is a bit weird.

I assume this data is coming from the meta data of one of the images. This raw data does not look suspicious.

Where should I start? This issue is causing getPost to fail.

Where is the bug tracker for this context so I can log a bug?

Comment: `This raw data does not look suspicious.` Does that mean you've checked the file itself and the parsed data doesn't match?

Comment: by raw data I'm referring to the meta data in image. The date was not say pre 1970 or something else corrupt. It was fairly recent. I don't know how it maps to wordpress so can check the "matching".

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry for the confusion. Hmm, have you checked the data in the database (it's serialized in post meta under `_wp_attachment_metadata`).